# Join multiple file names of files in a directory to a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with many files.

An executable `<executable>` has to be called with its name followed by all files in a directory (`file_1` ... `file_n`) and an `<outputfile>`:

Example:

```
executable file_1 ... file_n outputfile
```

How can I read all files from the same directory and produce a string as above that can be executed?

Comment: Are you currently in that directory? Are there also directories in it, or only files? Are there "hidden" files (with a name starting with `.`)?

Comment: And is `file_1` just the filename, or the path to a file?

Comment: I am in the directory of the files. `file_1` is just the file name.

Comment: Assuming that `outputfile` doesn't exist yet:  `executable file* outputfile` ;)  Of course there's the old limitation of "number of arguments".

Comment: this does not work, I need the string. E.g. for three files:  `executable file_1 file_2 file_3 ouputfile`

Comment: How about `executable  "$(echo *)" outfile`?

Comment: How are you going to use the string? The difficulty is in handling special characters and blanks in filenames; the common way to do that is to store the command in an array instead of a string.

Comment: The file names are without blanks

Comment: Creating a string to execute is generally a bad idea. Please [edit] your question to tell us what you're trying to do, rather than how you're trying to do it, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This script will print out the string you want with proper quoting on filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -v files '%q ' *
cmd="executable $files outputfile"
echo "$cmd"
```

You can actually execute the command with `eval "$cmd"`. Use of `eval` is safe here since filenames are quoted properly by `%q`, a `bash` specific `printf` conversion specification.